# What is the simplified of this summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

How can I simplify this equation into a single equation in terms of $n$?

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{(n-k-1)(n-k-2)+k(k+1)}$$

Comment: Split the sum in two, reverse the order of summation in the first. Combine again and recognise something vaguely known.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, in the mean-time I think I found the solution. It becomes some summation of squares. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @emab no, why? why don't you answer to your own question?

Comment: Please, do not delete your question ! You solved your problem and this is great; answer your own question in your post since it could be useful to other people to know how you proceeded.

There is no stupid question (answers could be) and all solutions are interesting to know.

The worst thing I saw was a question which received a few interesting and good answers; but as soon they appeared, the post was deleted by the owner.

For me, on this site, we share questions and solutions and this, at least to me, makes Math SE a fascinating site where everyone can learn a lot from other.

Comment: Done, now you may check whether the solution is correct or not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can split the summation,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{(n-k-1)(n-k-2)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{k(k+1)}$$

Now these two summations are equivalent,

$$2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{k(k+1)} = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{k^2 + k}=2 \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{k^2}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{k} \right)=2 \left( \frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-2)(n-1)(2n-3)}{6} \right)$$

Comment: That's right. Just to mention it: $3\cdot k(k+1) = (k+1)^3-k^3-1$, so $$2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} k(k+1) = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\left[(k+1)^3 - k^3 - 1\right] = \frac{2}{3}\left((n-1)^3 - 0^3 - (n-1)\right)=\frac{2}{3}(n-1)\left((n-1)^2-1\right) = \frac{2}{3}(n-2)(n-1)n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Although the problem has already been answered very nicely by OP and also by Daniel Fischer, here's a slightly different approach, using binomial coefficients, thus avoiding messy algebraic manipulations:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}[\underbrace{(n-k-1)}_{r+1}\underbrace{(n-k-2)}_r+k(k+1)]&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-2}r(r+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}k(k+1)\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}k(k+1)\\
&=4\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{k+1\choose2}\\
&=4{[(n-2)+1]+1\choose 2+1}\\
&=4{n\choose3}\\
&=\frac23 n(n-1)(n-2)\qquad \blacksquare\end{align}$$